# best practices on initializing user data in Angular 4 SPA after page reloads

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 4 SPA app and am using a userInit method in my singleton DataService to retrieve / manage global state of my user's data on login. Aside from initializing user data on login (which works fine), **I'm wondering what the best practice is for initializing user data on browser reloads** (i.e. an *authenticated user* reloads a deep link like mysite.com/user/preferences that is protected by an AuthGuard).

For now, my solution for this is to invoke the DataService.userInit method in my AuthGuard's canActivate method. This invocation helps to some extent with the challenge of ensuring all global user state is available after a page reload but doesn't initialize the data in time for the first page that's reloaded, so it's not ideal. (i.e. reload of mysite.com/user/preferences won't show user data on first load, since the preferences page renders before the dataService has again retrieved the data from the backend, but navigating away from the preferences page and back to it reveals the user data was reloaded when canActivate ran).

My questions:

1. Is the canActivate hook the best place to put my user initialization code (i.e. code that needs to run for users *already authenticated* that do a page reload), or are their other hooks I should consider?
2. How should I handle the issue of first reload? Please consider that I need to first authenticate the user and only then allow the userInit code to run, and if all that works render the requested page. I'm not looking to solve this for one particular page, but for any page that may rely on global data, hence am trying to figure out a good design pattern.
3. Wondering how others handle page reloads typically e.g. do you just re-route users back to the home page on reload? Or perhaps route them to an intermediary page and then back to the target page.

Any advice appreciated. Thank you,

- S. Arora

Comment: Either code your component by acknowledging the fact that the data is loaded asynchronously, and thus not available immediately, or use a resolver to resolve the asynchronous data and have the router provide it as part of the route snapshot.

Comment: re: handling async data -- in general I'm doing that throughout the application but I wasn't familiar enough with AuthGuards / canActivate to understand my options. On closer inspection canActivate simply returns true / false if the user is authenticated, so i can easily prevent it from returning true until the userInit method has completed. Thank you! If you post this as an answer i'll accept it. - S. Arora

Answer (score 0):

You should watch how well known websites (Twitter, Facebook, etc...) are managing their authenticated states; but basically, for authenticated state, there is an authentication token that you can keep in the LocalStorage that should expire after some time and a refresh token mecanism that allows the user to stay authenticated if he reloads (also used in the **remember me** option).

There is a good article that needs to be known : https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

1. You got another alternative, and I believe this one is better since it keeps your guard simple, and that should be the aim of the guard : Using a resolver at the module level on the routing.
2. It depends on what I wrote earlier and how your app architecture is made. After that it's all about resolves, services singletons, etc...
3. Basically the whole intro with token management, etc...

Comment: Appreciate the feedback but was not asking about how to authenticate / handle authentication etc. My question is focused on how to do user data initialization after page reloads for users that are already authenticated. The authentication piece I have a handle on.

Comment: My focus on this answer was more about how you can make the best authentification management overall, and use a resolver (as `JB Nizet` said) to manage your asynchronous data upon loading.
I believe well made guards with services and resolvers can make it pretty simple in the end, even though the toughest part is about thinking it well and bind everything together.
My pleasure, because after all thinking about this kind of high-end problematics is the best !

Comment: I agree resolvers appear to be a good option. From reading further they appear to be well-suited for more granular data initialization e.g. injecting component specific data. Since I'm trying to do global data initialization I went the path of modifying canActivate for now. Again, appreciate all the feedback., - S. Arora